# Headphone's Crackling

Tags: audio, pi-2

I got my new `Raspberry Pi 2` for a Christmas present, and I also got a new pair of headphones/headset. When I first plugged them in to the pi for the first time, it made some crackling noises in the background, as soon as I change the output from analog to HDMI, it stops and doesn't have the same issue on the HDMI. Is this the pi's fault or the headphones?

P.S. The headphones/headset I have is the `Turtle Beach Recon 50P`'s

Comment: Looks to me like a Pi issue. Can you check [these audio configurations](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md) and see if it helps? Thanks

Comment: This doesn't help, as it only explains how to use HDMI, and not the headphone jack @GirishSortur

Comment: Did you try updating your raspbian with the latest kernel? [Here's a detailed thread of the issue being discussed](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=95612) Hope this helps.

Comment: What OS are you running? Can you try adding the following line to /boot/config.txt   disable_audio_dither = 1   and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

**Plugging those (or pretty much any pair of headphones) into that socket is NOT a good idea.**

On the RPi Model's B+ and 2, the 3.5mm socket is a combined Stereo Audio **and Composite Video** output.  In order from tip to sleeve the four connections are:

- **Tip:** Left audio
- **Ring-1:** Right audio
- **Ring-2:** Ground
- **Sleeve:** Composite Video

[image: An image of a 3.5mm TRRS "Stereo audio and composite video" type jack plug]

Compared to the normal three pole 3.5 plug used for standard headphones the three pole plug will have a longer sleeve that extends to the tip-side of where Ring-2 is on the four pole one.  This means that **a normal headphone plug will short the Pi's composite video output to the ground connection**.[image: An image of a 3.5mm TRS "Stereo audio" type jack plug]

The particular headphones that the OP refers to, Turtle Beach Recon 50P, is a gaming headset that also has a microphone and the *four-pole* connector - however this suggests that Ring-2 and Sleeve are Ground and Microphone output or visa-versa. If the ground is Ring-2 then the Pi's Composite Video output is fed INTO the Microphone output from the headset which is not likely to be good for one or both devices.  If the ground is the Sleeve, then not only is the Pi's Composite Video fed into the Microphone as before but the sum of the Audio output from the Pi - once the two parts have flowed through the relevant headphone, will be connected to the Composite Video output of the Pi, and will either flow back into that output or add to the current being pushed into the Microphone on the Headset.  If that is a moving coil or a piezo device then it may even try to reproduce a combination of the audio signal sent to the headphones and (I guess) a 15KHz/50Hz line/field rate noise from the video signal.  So, at a minimum, **these Turtle Beach headphones will connect their microphone to the Pi's composite video out.**

If the composite video output conforms to normal standards it will have an impedance of 75 Ohms and be around 1Volt from sync-tip to peak-weak when connected to a 75 Ohm load or twice that if unloaded.  The schematic diagram for the older RPi (which has a separate RCA Phono connector for the compsite video output) has a 15 ohm resistor in series from the Broadcom CPU video DAC_OUT pin to the output connector and a direct connection from that connector to a second internal connection labelled DAC_TERM - this does suggest that shorting it to ground may not be the best thing to do.

---

Images from Wikipedia [Phone connector (audio)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29) article.